# Detect all touches on UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` which has `UICollectionViewCells` inside it. When a user touches the `UICollectionView` I want to be notified of this until they release their finger. I tried subclassing the `UICollectionView` like this:

```
final class MyCollectionView: UICollectionView {
    var hasTouch = false

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
        hasTouch = true
    }

    override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesCancelled(touches, with: event)
        hasTouch = false
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
        hasTouch = false
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work when there are cells in the way because they don't pass their touches on to the collection view. One way of solving this is to set `userInteractionEnabled` to false on the cells, but I can't do that because I do need `userInteractionEnabled` to be true on the cells. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Redesign the interaction. You're trying to do two incompatible things with the collectionview, and swimming uphill against UIKit that way will only lead to tears. It also goes against the expectations of your users, who have seen a lot of collectionviews and expect them to act a certain way.

If you really insist on doing this, what you could do is:

1. set userInteractionEnabled to false on the cells.
2. on touch down, check to see if you touched down on a cell, using indexPathForItemAtPoint: (the point is where the touch was)
3. on touch up, use indexPathforItemAtPoint to see if you are in the same cell. Then, you could manually deal with "selecting a cell"
4. Then do whatever other stuff you are doing with the touches as well.

Basically, turn userInteractionEnabled off, and handle cell selection yourself.